# How can I stop jQuery Mobile doing a full page refresh after a certain sequence of page links?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have my several pages in my jQuery Mobile application and they are all contained in separate files. I have a situation where the first page transitions to the second page using the default Ajax transition. When I click the Back button from page two, I get a normal Ajax reverse transition and the form context of page 1 is the same as when I left, eg selections are all the same. Note that when I click Back, I don't see the 'Loading...' popup message.

I have a third page that is linked to from page 2 and I need this to be data-ajax="false" because it contains Facebook Like tags that must be expanded. I find that if I use Ajax transition, these are not processed. My problem is that after I have done a non-Ajax link to page 3, all subsequent transitions then seem to completely refresh the page, although they are Ajax because I see my standard 'Ajax loading' popup. But because it is a full page refresh, I lose my form context each time, including from page 2 back to page 1. Like this:

Page 1 > Page 2 < Page 1 (all works okay, page 1 is same as when I left it)

Page 1 > Page 2 > Page 3 < Page 2 < Page 1 (transition from 2 to 1 full refresh, probably Ok)

Page 1 > Page 2 < Page 1 (page 1 is reset each time, unlike the initial behaviour for those 2 pages)

So it seems that going through the non-Ajax route has broken the links between pages 1 and 2 even after returning to them afresh.

Has anybody else noticed this behaviour or can suggest a fix for it? Note that all my pages are proper jQuery Mobile-marked-up pages with header, footer and a div with data-role="page"; my back links are these:

```
<a class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="back" data-rel="back" data-role="button" href="/">back</a>
```

Comment: To clarify what is happening here I put an alert in the pagecreate event of page 1. This fires on initial load, obviously, but not when I click back from page 2 to 1. However, when I have been through any non-Ajax link and returned to page 1, back links from page 2 to page 1 always trigger pagecreate. This is why the form is being reset to its initial state each time.

Comment: Did you happen to check "Known limitations" section in this link - http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html ?

Comment: Yes, I'd read that thanks. However, I went back to that page and read the section on disabling pushState, which they recommend if you use lots of rel=external or non-Ajax links. I did that and my links seem to be working logically now - I mean I get a full refresh coming back from non-Ajax but Ajax and back links work normally after that. I also noticed that if I put breaks and alerts in the pageinit and pagecreate handlers, that worked as well, presumably by interfering with page load times. Bit random though. Thanks

Comment: I would also suggest reading this: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-links.html

Comment: Read that, several times, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply the following attribute **data-ajax="false"** to your link e.g.

```
<a class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="back" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-ajax="false" href="/">
```

That should fix it.

Mentioned in http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-links.html

Comment: Please read the question carefully before answering. I want an Ajax transition between 2 and 1 but am getting a non-Ajax transition after coming back from a non-Ajax page 3.